# How can I fix these errors in this little program in C++?

Tags: c++

Is a program of a book: Author: Bjarne.

The SECESC listing. cev uses escape sequences, stories like making sounds (beeps) in the terminal twice and then a continuation of two backspace blanks.

```
// int function int main
// Progama:SECESC.CPP
// Autor J.R. Mortimer
// Proposito: Mostrar funcionamiento de secuencias de escape

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

main()
{
    char sonidos = O\a°; // Secuancia de escape alarma en sonidos //[Error] stray '\' in program
                                                               //[Error] stray '\260' in program
                                                               //[Error] stray expected ',' or';' before
                                                                                                  'a'
    char bs = \b;       // Almacena secuencia de escape retroceso en bs //[Error] stray '\' in program
                                                                      //[Error] 'b' was not declared in
                                                                      //scope
    cout << sonidos;    // Envia secuencia de escape al terminal
    cout << sonidos;    // Envia secuencia de escape al teminal
    cout << "ZZ";       // Emite el sonido dos veces
    cout << bs;         // Emite secuencia de escapes al terminal
    cout << bs;         // Mueve el cursor al primer caracter
    return 0;           // Retorno de 0
}
```

Comment: You need to wrap `char` literals in `''` as in `'a'`

Comment: It can't have been like that in a book. And who is Bjarne? [Bjarne Stroustrup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bjarne_Stroustrup)?

Comment: `\a` is the C escape sequence for the [ASCII Bell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Control_code_chart) (Ctrl + G, 0x07).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`char` literals are surrounded by the `'` symbol. So for example, you need to write

```
char sonidos = '\a';   // beep
```